# Microsoft.IdentityModel vs System.IdentityModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif

I'm working on a claims-based authorization system using Forms Authentication and ASP.NET MVC 2. I see that one namespace "Microsoft.IdentityModel" provides a lot of the same things as the other "System.IdentityModel".

[System.IdentityModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.aspx)

[Microsoft.IdentityModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.aspx)

Why do these 2 namespaces exist seperately, when the functionality appears to overlap?

Comment: Not to thread jack but I got burned hard by using WIF, absolutely set it up in an ACTIVE STS configuration. WIF is not capable of functioning reliably in a passive ONLY configuration.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

If you are using Claims Based authentication/authorization, then you will need to use Microsoft.IdentityModel as that is part of the Windows Identity Framework.

For guidance around MVC2 and using WIF I would recommend checking out the [work that Patterns and Practices](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/) did. They have a decent MVC sample that I used as a starting point.

Answer (score 57):

Microsoft.IdentityModel is used by WIF in .NET 4.0 and version before. System.IdentityModel is to be used in .NET 4.5 and beyond.
More details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157091.aspx

Comment: It's 2023 now, and `Microsoft.IdentityModel` still lives on as [`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions), [`Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens), and a few others - while [`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt) is also still active - oh, and now there's [`IdentityModel`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel) too. This is confusing :S

Comment: IdentityModel is a private repository not associated with MS-
https://github.com/IdentityModel.
Libraries usually hang around for backwards compatibility, but you should use the newest version you can as they usually work better and give you some newer options.